# Changing the close button icon in Bootstrap modal with FontAwesome icon

Tags: bootstrap-modal, font-awesome

I want to change the close icon in bootstrap modal from `&times;` to `<i class="fas fa-times-circle"></i>` using FontAwesome, but when I do, the close button stops working and even if I click it it does not close the modal. FontAwesome is installed and I can see all the icons.

This works (default Bootstrap modal):

```
   <div class="modal fade" id="<%= product.units[key].mini %>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="ModalCenter" aria-hidden="true">
     <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content modal-view-model">
       <div class="modal-header justify-content-center">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
         <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
       </div>
       <div class="modal-body pt-0">
       <img src="model.png">
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
```

This doesn't:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="<%= product.units[key].mini %>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="ModalCenter" aria-hidden="true">
 <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
  <div class="modal-content modal-view-model">
   <div class="modal-header justify-content-center">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
     <span aria-hidden="true"><i class="fas fa-times-circle"></i></span>
    </button>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-body pt-0">
   <img src="model.png">
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```